# Matlab LBP Real Valued

Tags: matlab, binary, feature-extraction, vision, lbph-algorithm

MATLAB's built in function to compute local binary patterns, from the computer vision toolbox, produces real valued numbers.
The function is named: `extractLBPFeatures()`

I understood the values from LBP to be binary - it's in the name!
What is it doing to get real valued numbers rather than binary values?

Comment: You misunderstood. The pattern is only binary after comparing each pixel to is neighbors, and before concatenating those binary values in to a larger (say, 8-bit) number, calculating the histogram over the cell, and performing L2 normalization.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Matlab documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractlbpfeatures.html), the call `extractLBPFeatures(<your_image>)` returns a *1*-by-*59* vector representing the *L<sub>2</sub>*-normalized histogram of the **non rotation-invariant uniform LBPs**, i.e. the relative frequencies of these 59 possible patterns throughout the image. The code of a non rotation-invariant uniform LBP formed by 8 neighbouring pixels is a whole number ranging from 0 to 58, whereas the 59 components of the feature vector yielded by `extractLBPFeatures` are floating point numbers in the range 0..1.

If you wish to obtain an image where the pixel intensity values are replaced by the LBP codes you could use the [Matlab implementation](http://www.cse.oulu.fi/wsgi/MVG/Downloads/LBPMatlab) developed by the creators of the LBP descriptor.